# laravel / How to store the random number with the requests in the database

Tags: laravel-5

I have a field in the in_out model that I want to insert with the requests in the database?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


  $validatedData = $request->validate([
     'name' => 'required|max:255',

                 'type' => 'required|max:255',
 ]);


 $add = in_out::create($validatedData);




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to understand.

This is an implementation in case you want to add attributes after validation and before storing on DB.

```
use App\InOut;

class InOutController
{
    ...

    public function store(\Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];

        $attributes = $request->validate($rules);

        $attributes['description'] = 'Adding a description after validation and before store on database';

        $inOut = InOut::create($attributes);

        return redirect('/inout')->with('inOut', $inOut)->with('status', 'InOut created.');
    }

    ...
}
```